# google analytics 360 API vs GA Core Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am currently using the regular Google Analytics Core Reporting API, but will have a possible client using Google Analytics 360 for their Goal Completions/Conversions.  My question is, will I be able to use the same Core Reporting API for a client that is a Google Analytics 360 user?  Or is there a better API to use for Google Analytics 360 clients?

Comment: I don't know who closed voted this opinion based.   The fact is are there are two different versions of the API and one of them allows for additional dimensions and metrics which are usable by 360 customers that are not supported in the older version.   This is not an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better API for GA 360. Anything you built for a standard account using the Core Reporting API will keep on working for a GA 360 account.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that the [Core reporting API is V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) there is a newer version of the API called the  [Reporting API is v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/).  You should consider switching to the Reporting API just because its newer, but also because it gives addition of a number of dimensions and metrics which are available to 360 users and are not available in v3 namely [Lifetime Value and Cohorts - Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=lifetime_value_and_cohorts)

Comment: I am currently using the Reporting API v4 to get metrics from GA, and the Management API to get goal information (Ids, Goal Completions, etc.).  Would my current set up work exactly the same way for a Google 360 Analytics user?  How will my script know whether a client is a google 360 user or not?  Do I have to specifically call this out in the code?

Comment: @MartinEdran were you ever able to determine, possible by API, whether a client is a google 360 user or not?